# Just check status process in c

Tags: c, process, fork, wait

I want to know the status of a process. I think I can use the wait family functions but actually I don't want to wait for the process, just check the status and go on.

I would want something like

```
checkStatusOfProcess(&status);
if(status == WORKING) {
    //do something
} else if(status == exited) {
    //do something else
} else \\I dont care about other states
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Then you want to use the `waitpid` function with the `WNOHANG` option:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int status;
pid_t return_pid = waitpid(process_id, &status, WNOHANG); /* WNOHANG def'd in wait.h */
if (return_pid == -1) {
    /* error */
} else if (return_pid == 0) {
    /* child is still running */
} else if (return_pid == process_id) {
    /* child is finished. exit status in   status */
}
```

Comment: What if process we are interesting in finished and system starts another process with the same process id? How we can distinguish these two processes?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want [`waitpid`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/waitpid.html) with `WNOHANG`.

```
waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
```

Comment: that would continue execution?

Answer (score 1):

Kill it with signal 0 and check return value.