# In Node.js, how do I determine if a child process has started without errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, child-process

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('some-command');
```

I know I can guard against `ENOENT` (when `some-command` doesn't exist) with

```
child.on('error', function(err) { ... })
```

Now, how do I asynchronously determine *the process is running **and** no error has happened*?

---

I could listen for `error` and `close` events, but that still leaves the case of "*is running*" looking identical to "*the operating system hasn't gotten around to looking for the file yet*", which can cause nasty race conditions.

An `open`-event would be nice, but [the docs](https://iojs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) don't mention one.

Does a functional workaround exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The information you are looking for (process running, no errors) is not available from the Host OS in such an easy-to-use format.

Unless the child process prints something that is parsed and tracked (by code you or someone will have to write) in node, or exits with a status code, there is no indication available from the OS that nodejs or iojs can obtain from a system call and wrap in a JS API for the developer.

At least on Linux, the operating system status of a process is limited to one of:

1. process is running; OR
2. process has exit (status number indicates OK or ERROR); OR
3. non-existent (no such PID)

Furthermore, once the exit status has been retrieved with `wait()` or `waitpid()`, it is no longer available.

The idea of an "error" is often application dependent and these application errors are not tracked by the operating system -- except for the exit status integer the process reports when it exits.

To give a clearer example, many apps have commands that open files for processing, and will print an error message when an input file can not be opened and proceed to the next command.  This failure is not part of a process status that is tracked by PID in the operating system and kept in memory somewhere so it can be read from another process. It may appear in the stderr or stdout stream and can be read that way, but requires specific coding for it to be interpreted correctly by parent or other processes.  Alternatively, other apps will exit immediately when something has gone seriously wrong, and set exit status to a non-zero number, indicating error.  That exit status and the fact that the process terminated are available from the operating system.

See also:  [Just check status process in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200373/just-check-status-process-in-c)