# How to check if child process is finished in c by its pid

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

I am building a very tiny shell in c,

I have the option on running programs in the background.

I keep a list of all my jobs meaning all the ones in the bg.

Now if i want to go and update this list, how can i check is a process is finished or if its still running.

ps
if i waited with waitpid for some process, will i still be able to check if the process is done? (i mean if i used waitpid it took the process of zombie state.

Comment: I think you should post your code. I didn't understand what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just check status process in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200373/just-check-status-process-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to call `waitpid`, passing it the process id and the `WNOHANG` option and call the `WIFEXITED` macro on the integer returned through status argument.  See [Just check status process in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200373/just-check-status-process-in-c).

Comment: Arthur, while the answer is correct, it is entirely based on the answer you cite in your answer. When you find that occurring, it is far better to mark this question as a *duplicate* of the one you cite. This allows all questions/answers regarding a particular topic to be collected in one place and helps prevent SO from becoming hopelessly fragmented. To mark this question as a duplicate of the other, simply choose the *close* option beneath the original question and enter the *URL* for the original.