# How to track termination/running of child process that is not being "waited" for?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, process

I have an assignment where I have to write a subshell in C++. Essentially, I am forking (if the input is not jobs or exit) and in the child process, I am calling exec to run the command. It needs to run alongside the parent process, so for example if I call sleep 100, the program should immediately be ready to run the next command since the parent is not "waiting" for it since I am using WNOHANG. However, my issue is when I need to track the actual state- if sleep is still running, I want to be able to get that the command is still running, but I am unable to do so. It always shows up as exited, when I use the various macros. I have no idea how to approach this differently and would appreciate some guidance.
 (i didn't include the declarations of the variables since the editor on this website was messing it up for some reason)

```
    do{

        cout << "# ";
        getline(cin, input);

        if (input == "jobs")
        {
            cout << "Process ID | State        | Command " << endl;
            cout << "-----------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------" << endl;

            //jobs stuff goes here, need to print pids, states, and commands

            if(counter == 0)
            {
                cout << " [NO PROCESSES] " << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
                {
                    cout << pidArray[i] << " ";
                    cout << statusArray[i] << " ";
                    cout << cmdArray[i] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cmdArray[i] = input;
            i++;
            counter++;
            pid = fork();

            if( pid == 0)
            {
                execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", input.c_str(), (char *)0);
                //break;
            }
            else if (pid == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                pidArray[i-1] = pid;
                //int rc = waitid(P_PID, pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
                // int rc =waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG | WNOWAIT );
                //exitChecker = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

                usleep(100000);

                if (WIFEXITED(status))
                {
                    cout << "terminated" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "running" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }while(input != "exit");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help then edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200373/just-check-status-process-in-c.

Comment: How about trapping the SIGCHLD signal? Assume that each child processes is still running, unless you have caught a SIGCHLD for that process. In the SIGCHLD handler you can call `waitpid(..., WNOHANG)`, as you currently do. Be aware that, in principle, you might get a single SIGCHLD for multiple child processes.

Comment: I talked to my professor, and he said to use waitid. So i am using the command 
waitid(P_PID, pid, &info, WNOHANG | WCONTINUED | WEXITED | WSTOPPED);

(where info is a siginfo_t structure)

my issue now is being able to access the CLD_EXITED, CLD_TRAPPED, and other signal codes. every time I run a process it comes si_code has a value of 0, which I don't understand.